# Comment URL formatting broken

Tags: support, markdown

The rendering of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266970/onframeavailable-callback-is-not-coming/46405790?noredirect=1#comment83658301_46405790) includes the markup [ and has truncated the anchor text. Here's how it looks to me in Chrome on OSX (although I doubt the platform is relevant):

[image]

Here is the comment in plain text:

```
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)](The documentation) makes no mention of that. Also none of the three calls to onFrameAvailable in the grafika examples use the GL thread and in fact the comments for [https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/bc29f6715f25ff841f96f6faa9ccd12d89d9ef97/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L397](this implementation) say you need to call updateTexImage on the surface owner thread (GL in this case).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong format.

As per the [Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links), the inline link format is `[Google](http://www.google.com/)`

So the plain text should be:

```
[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture\(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture\)) makes no mention of that. Also none of the three calls to onFrameAvailable in the grafika examples use the GL thread and in fact the comments for [this implementation](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/bc29f6715f25ff841f96f6faa9ccd12d89d9ef97/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L397) say you need to call updateTexImage on the surface owner thread (GL in this case).
```

and it will render as:

> [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture)) makes no mention of that. Also none of the three calls to onFrameAvailable in the grafika examples use the GL thread and in fact the comments for [this implementation](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/bc29f6715f25ff841f96f6faa9ccd12d89d9ef97/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L397) say you need to call updateTexImage on the surface owner thread (GL in this case).

In case, if `(` and `)` are coming inside the URL, you can escape it by `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: Testing the above in comments box: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture\(android.graphics.SurfaceTexture\)) makes no mention of that. Also none of the three calls to onFrameAvailable in the grafika examples use the GL thread and in fact the comments for [this implementation](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/bc29f6715f25ff841f96f6faa9ccd12d89d9ef97/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L397) say you need to call updateTexImage on the surface owner thread (GL in this case).

Comment: RTFM! I blame Friday :-)